# Python Scrapy web-crawling and scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm writing a Scrapy Spider to traverse through a travel website. The structure of the website is the following:

```
Continents
    North America
        USA
            lat: 123
            long: 456
        Canada
            lat: 123
            long: 456
    South America
        Brazil
            lat: 456
            long: 789
        Peru
            lat: 123
            long: 456
```

I have figured out how to crawl to each country page and grab lat/long info using the script below but what I'm having difficulty with is storing the information.

```
import scrapy


class WorldSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "world"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'www.world.com'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            # yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_region)

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css(CONTINENT_SELECTOR):
            continent = link.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if continent is not None:
                continent = response.urljoin(continent)
                yield response.follow(continent, callback=self.parse_continent)

    def parse_continent(self, continent_response):
        country_urls = continent_response.css(COUNTRY_SELECTOR)
        if len(country_urls) == 0:
            # This if-statement is entered when the Spider is at a country web page (e.g. USA, Canada, etc.).
            # TODO figure out how to store this to text file or append to JSON object
            yield {
                'country': continent_response.css(TITLE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'latitude' : continent_response.css(LATITUDE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'longitude' : continent_response.css(LONGITUDE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
            }

        for link in country_urls:
            country = link.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if area is not None:
                yield continent_response.follow(continent_response.urljoin(area), callback=self.parse_continent)
```

How do I write this information to a file or to a JSON object? I would ideally like the structure of the data to capture the structure of the website.

example:

```
{
    "continents": [
        {"North America" : [
            {"country" : {"title": "USA", "latitude" : 123, "longitude" : 456}},
            {"country" : {"title": "Canada", "latitude" : 123, "longitude" : 456}}
        ]},
        {"South America" : [
            {"country" : {"title": "Brazil", "latitude" : 456, "longitude" : 789}},
            {"Peru" : {"title": "Peru", "latitude" : 123, "longitude" : 456}}
        ]}          
    ]
}
```

How should I modify my Spider to achieve this above goal?

Comment: You will need [**a pipeline**](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file)

Comment: @Jan Thanks for your input. I'm still ramping up on Scrapy, so knowing what to look at in the documentation is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing data in files can be done in two ways. First is as @Jan mentioned, using the [JsonWritePipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file), where such method is recommended when the scrapy spider is run many times and is used to append to the file each time.

Following is an example of such execution:

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
          f.write(response.body)
self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Though the simplest method is to use the [Feed Export](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-exports) options that allows for easier implementation.

> Feed Exports which allows you to generate a feed with the scraped items, using multiple serialization formats and storage backends.
>   For serializing the scraped data, the feed exports use the Item 
>   exporters. These formats are supported out of the box:
>
> ```
>     JSON
>     JSON lines
>     CSV
>     XML
> ```

Following is an example of using FileExport to store data as a JSON file:

```
$scrapy crawl myExample -o output.json
```

> **Note :**  Scrapy appends to a given file instead of overwriting its contents. If
>   you run this command twice without removing the file before the second
>   time, you’ll end up with a broken JSON file.

As for the **structure** of data in JSON, I prefer working with [Item](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) as it provides you with a very clear structure in mind and with many depth JSONs is preferable for verifying the structure.

For your implementation, the structure should be declared as :

```
import scrapy

class Address(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    latitude = scrapy.Field()
    longitude = scrapy.Field()

class Place(scrapy.Item):
    country = scrapy.Field()         #object of Address

class Continents(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()             #array of Place
```

I'll let you figure out how to implement that ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Scrapy provides this functionality out of the box with the Feed Exports, which allows you to generate a feed with the scraped items, using multiple serialization formats and storage backends.

```
scrapy crawl WorldSpider -o name.json -t json
```

will save the parsed items.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll take a peek at Feed Exports in the Scrapy Documentation.